# Set a datetime field configured as date-only

Tags: 8, entities, datetime

I'm developing a module where I have to set a user profile date_field. I tried several methods to implement this but not one worked for me.

This is the code I am using.

```
private function updateUser($user_import,$uid = null) {
  if (!$uid) {
    return false;
  }

  $roles = $this->matchRoles($user_import->roles);
  $birthday = $this->birthdayDate($user_import->profile_geburtsdatum);
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
  // $user->setPassword($this->randomPassword());
  $user->setEmail($user_import->mail);
  $user->setUsername($user_import->name);
  $user->enforceIsNew(false);

  // Optional settings
  $user->set("init", $user_import->init);
  $user->set("langcode", $language);
  $user->set("preferred_langcode", $language);
  $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $language);

  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $user->addRole($role);
  }

  $user->set("field_profile_geburtsdatum", array('#default_value' => $birthday));
  $user->activate();
  $user->save();

  drupal_set_message("UPDATE: User " . $user_import->name . ' ( '. $user_import->mail . ')');
}

private function birthdayDate($import_date) {
  $date = null;
  if (!empty($import_date)) {
    $date = strtotime($import_date->day.'.'.$import_date->month.'.'.$import_date->year);
    $date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',$date);
    $date = new \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime($date, 'Europe/Berlin');

    /* $date = array(
         'year' => date('Y',$date),
         'month' => date('m',$date),
         'day' => date('d',$date),
       );
     */
  }

  return $date;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `field_profile_geburtsdatum` is configured as a singular date-only datetime field, the following are all equivalent in the Field API (in order of my preferred usage):

```
$user->field_profile_geburtsdatum = '1999-12-31';
$user->field_profile_geburtsdatum->value = '1999-12-31';
$user->field_profile_geburtsdatum->set(0, '1999-12-31');
$user->set('field_profile_geburtsdatum', ['1999-12-31']);
```

The value you set should be a string in the `DATETIME_DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT`, which is `'Y-m-d'`, and not a DrupalDateTime object.  That is used internally by the field type.

Answer (score 3):

Since [Drupal 8.5.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.5.0) this works a little differently.

Firstly it's good practice to set the **timezone** explicitly so you know what is going on:

- See PHP's [list of supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
- Get the default time zone using [date_default_timezone_get()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php). Please note [drupal_get_user_timezone()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_user_timezone/8.9.x) is deprecated since Drupal 8.8.0 and removed from Drupal 9.0.0.
- Use Drupal's storage timezone [`DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItemInterface.php/constant/DateTimeItemInterface%3A%3ASTORAGE_TIMEZONE/).

Set the timezone:

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
// Or
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
// Or 
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE);
```

Then create the date object using the [PHP DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date_time = new \DateTime('now', $timezone);
$drupal_date_time = DrupalDateTime::createFromDateTime($date_time);
```

Or the [DrupalDateTime class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/class/DrupalDateTime/):

```
$drupal_date_time = new DrupalDateTime('yesterday', $timezone);
```

I like to use `DateTime` (or [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php)) and then pass into the `DrupalDateTime` wrapper. That way native methods are highlighted in the IDE and also date comparisons (e.g. `$now > $somedatetime` [work reliably](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3058010).

Prior to saving the **date/time** you must set the timezone to `DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE`:

```
$drupal_date_time->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE))
```

You can then format the date for storage using the the [DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItemInterface.php/constant/DateTimeItemInterface%3A%3ADATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT/) constant:

```
$drupal_date_time->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT)
```

Here is an example based on above use case:

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');

// geburtsdatum = 'date of birth' :-)
$birthday_import_object = $user_import->profile_geburtsdatum;

$day = $birthday_import_object->day;
$month = $birthday_import_object->month;
$year = $birthday_import_object->year;

$birthday = new \DateTime($day.' '.$month.' '.$year, $timezone);

// Optionally convert to DrupalDateTime if you need the custom methods, etc
$birthday = DrupalDateTime::createFromDateTime($birthday);

$user->set(
  'field_profile_geburtsdatum',
  $birthday
    ->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE))
    ->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT)
);
```

Comment: You should put the backslashes back. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/namespaces#s-use-ing-classes. Also look how core does it.

Comment: Fair point @leymannx. It just doesn't look as pretty!

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->set('field_profile_geburtsdatum', [['value' => $birthday]]);
```

There are two issues with the call to `set` in the question.

1. A field requires to set an indexed array of values. This will call FieldItemBase::setValue().
2. Each array within the values array should be keyed by the properties of that field. In this case `value`, not `#default_value`.

It is understandably confusing because as of this time there is no clear documentation around setting field items in either the Entity API section of Develop for Drupal or on api.drupal.org.

Comment: It's not clear where this would best be added (in the typed data section of entity api? wait until the docs pages are all migrated?), but it would probably be best to make the parameters in FieldableEntityInterface::set much more verbose instead of the dubious `mixed` type.