# Why doesn't my date get rendered?

Tags: datetime

In Drupal 8, I have a **Flag** entity with a date field attached.

My code looks like this:

```
function MYMODULE_flagging_presave(FlaggingInterface $flagging) {
    if ($score == 0 || $score == 1) {
      $flagging->field_date_review = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today'));
    }
    else {
      $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$interval days"));
      $flagging->field_date_review = $date;
    }
```

I checked and the dates get stored in the database like `2020-07-02`.

I have a custom view that shows these flaggings, and I added a filter for nodes with a date field value of less than +1 days; this behaves as expected, so the Views module seems to understand the dates as I stored them.

But, when I try to add the date **field**, I get an empty display in Views.

**Further debugging**

When I render the flagging entity, the date field doesn't show a value, either.

Other fields set in ``hook_flagging_presave()` are displayed correctly; it's only the date field that doesn't have a value.

**Configuration**

On the flagging entity's *Manage display* screen, I have set my date field to use the *Plain* format with no timezone offset. I also tried the *Default* format and several others, but nothing let me display the value.

There are no errors in the recent log messages.

To sum up: the date field has data in the database, which Views can see and use for filters.  But, this date field cannot be displayed in Views or on the rendered flagging entity.

What do I need to do to get the date to be displayed?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the Views config. Also, does the date show up on the regular view node page?

Comment: @beltouche Thanks, the problem doesn't seem to be Views.  Updated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the date using what is a more standard construct: `$flagging->set('field_date_review', $date)`?

Comment: @beltouche I tried that construct, same result; it is saved to DB but not displayed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set date field in D8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214164/set-date-field-in-d8)

Comment: @4k4 Thanks, that's an informative question.  But my question stemmed from a confusion between date and datetime, which is not directly addressed in the linked question.

Comment: The linked question stemmed from the same confusion and then @mpdonadio addressed it in the comments and answer. See also the second answer how to use [DateTimeItemInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItemInterface.php/interface/DateTimeItemInterface/9.0.x) when handling this field type.

Comment: @PatrickKenny - What does the date look like in the DB if you set the value from the UI instead of via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it-- the **Date** field can store *dates* or *datetimes*, and you have to change your code for each case.

When you add a **Date** field to an entity, you can choose *Date* (*date*) or *Date and time* (*datetime*) as the **Date type**.

[More information in this blog post](https://gorannikolovski.com/blog/set-date-field-programmatically), but the basic idea is:

```
$node->set('field_date', date('Y-m-d', time()));
$node->set('field_datetime', date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time()));
```